Crash with MKLit 4.0.0 - [MLKImageLabeler resultsInImage:error:] + 132
I have an app that is able to reproduce the following crash issue with the following Pod dependencies
  - GoogleMLKit/ImageLabeling (4.0.0):
    - GoogleMLKit/MLKitCore
    - MLKitImageLabeling (~> 3.0.0)

And the crash log looks like the following.
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ed09742c __pthread_kill + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000200e36c0c pthread_kill + 268 (pthread.c:1721)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001abf3ac34 __abort + 136 (abort.c:159)
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001abf3abac abort + 192 (abort.c:126)
4   AppName                         0x00000001023b78fc MLKITx_absl::log_internal::LogMessage::FailWithoutStackTrace() + 20
5   AppName                         0x00000001023b7dfc MLKITx_absl::log_internal::LogMessage::Die() + 36
6   AppName                         0x00000001023b7b74 MLKITx_absl::log_internal::LogMessage::SendToLog() + 128
7   AppName                         0x00000001023b7488 MLKITx_absl::log_internal::LogMessage::Flush() + 316
8   AppName                         0x00000001023b7f3c MLKITx_absl::log_internal::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal() + 20
9   AppName                         0x00000001023b7f64 MLKITx_absl::log_internal::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal() + 12
10  AppName                         0x00000001023e1a84 visionkit::Pipeline::Process(long long, unsigned char const*, int, int, int, int) (.cold.1) + 52
11  AppName                         0x0000000101138630 visionkit::Pipeline::Process(long long, unsigned char const*, int, int, int, int) + 488
12  AppName                         0x0000000101135094 -[MLKITvk_VNKPipeline processPixelBuffer:imageOrientation:externalDetections:error:] + 480
13  AppName                         0x0000000101134e64 -[MLKITvk_VNKPipeline processPixelBuffer:imageOrientation:error:] + 100
14  AppName                         0x0000000101135314 -[MLKITvk_VNKPipeline processImage:error:] + 104
15  AppName                         0x00000001011353f0 -[MLKITvk_VNKPipeline processImage:imageOrientation:error:] + 120
16  AppName                         0x000000010113205c -[MLKVisionKitImageLabeler labelsInImage:error:] + 160
17  AppName                         0x000000010112736c -[MLKDefaultImageLabeler labelsInImage:beginTime:error:] + 100
18  AppName                         0x0000000101126d08 -[MLKDefaultImageLabeler resultsInImage:error:] + 128
19  AppName                         0x0000000101128554 -[MLKImageLabeler resultsInImage:error:] + 132
20  AppName                         0x0000000100d03650 closure #1 in MLPhotoScanner.computePhotoLabels(image:) + 68 (MLPhotoScanner.swift:XXX)

The issue can be reproduced very infrequently but due to the high install base, I am still able to see the error from the crash report in XCode. Note that I have done the following to remediate the issue but none of them works.

I tried to have the GoogleMLKit/ImageLabeling kit but as I still have users staying with a very legacy iOS version, 4.0.0 is the highest version that I can download and install.
I tried to catch the error with the try/catch block with the following block, but that does not work well (feel free to reference the following code if anybody wants to catch the errors from ObjectiveC but are writing codes in Swift).

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@protocol ExceptionCatcher <NSObject>

NS_INLINE NSException * _Nullable tryBlock(void(^_Nonnull tryBlock)(void)) {
    @try {
        tryBlock();
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        return exception;
    }
    return nil;
}

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END

But the following code still throws error.
let exception = tryBlock {
   imageLabels = (try? labeler.results(in: visionImage)) ?? []
}
guard exception == nil else { return [] }

So I am looking for suggestions to avoid the above error (by setting some configuration, or handle some corner cases?) or a way to fully capture the above crash codes. Any inputs are welcomed.
